# Create Dynamic Footer on Masterpage Updated by Non-Programmer

Tags: master-page, footer

I have a nice footer with a list of Links, Images and Text.  I've added this to the Masterpage and has worked out nice since it has been pretty much static, that is, until now.  Our Publishing team would like to be able to manage the footer themselves. They are not programmers, and I don't want to continually upload the Masterpage or re-deploy a solution every time the footer content needs changed.

Any ideas on how I can let them managed footer content easily?

Bismarck

Comment: Could potentially use the Reusable HTML list and incorporate those snippets into your master page

Comment: You could add a control that takes information from a Managed Metadata term set and then allow them to update the term set as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a [post](http://www.sharplogic.net/display-content-from-reusable-html-list-in-a-masterpage) from Steve Clements that shows how to use the Reusable HTML Content in a Publishing Site as a User Control added to the Masterpage.